# Asynchronous issue within nodejs/mongodb code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I am new to nodejs/express/mongodb/jade and I have been trying for some time now to put together a simple site to help facilitate a more efficient way of reaching back to past data and being able to reuse it quickly. I determined the easiest way to us it would be do have a dynamic URL and had started to make good progress and then ran into a road block.

End Goal: I am looking to use the URL params to determine which data is returned. Ran locally the syntax would look like localhost/:collection/:id. As an example it'd look like: localhost/lastyear/aug2001. Thus the resulting page would display the data in the collection lastyear where the _ID is equal to aug2001.

To achieve this I currently I have the route in index.js set as:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:collection/:id', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get(req.params.collection);
    var entry = collection.findOne({ id: req.params.id },{})
    res.render('dataentry',{ title: 'Information for: ' + req.params.collection + ' ' + req.params.id +'.', data: entry
    });   
});

module.exports = router;
```

The structure of a doc within the collection looks as something as follows:

```
{
     "_id": "aug2001"
     "header": "header text"
     "content": "content text"
     "item" : "items text"
}
```

For testing to see some form of data my jade file for dataentry looks as follows(I know tabbing is important in jade and it may not look correct here in the post but I made sure the tabs are correct):

```
block content 
     p Finding info...
     p= data.header
     p= data.content
     p= data.item
```

When navigating to /lastyear/aug2001 all I see is the page load "Finding info..." and I am not sure what I am missing as far as the jade syntax goes in order to display the doc data. I appreciate any help/suggestions of a more efficient way to achieve my end result.

EDIT:
The real issue was not with JADE displaying but rather a asynchronous db call when pulling data out of the db.

Comment: there's a lot going on here - as a first step, you should try to isolate your problem. for example, is the problem in the Jade or in the db query? to test this you might e.g. write `console.log(entry);` right before `res.render()` to see if the database object is being found properly. if you don't see what you expect, you know your problem is in your db calls, not your Jade.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. There is definitely a lot going on here and I appreciate the comment. I went ahead and added in the code and although I'm not too familiar with the standard output of console.log(), the output did not look correct. I went ahead and added it to a working tutorial I had prior to starting my own project and when running it there in the console is shows the actual data structure of the doc within the collection. Therefore, there is something wrong with my db call. Thanks for the help. Will update/edit question as I work through the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i see you have asynchronous problem here.

Try like this

```
router.get('/:collection/:id', function(req, res) {
   var db = req.db;
   var collection = db.get(req.params.collection);
   //this is async operation so you need to wait until it finish.
   //and only then send response to page.
   collection.findOne({ id: req.params.id },{}, function(err, entry){
      res.render('dataentry',{ title: 'Information for: ' + req.params.collection + ' ' + req.params.id +'.', data: entry
      });  
   }); 
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and help. I am no longer receiving null results in my db calls. Thank you.

Comment: Np.Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

**Code not checked**

---

As @Mykola Borysyuk mentioned, this seems to be an asynchronous callback problem. In your code, `collection.findOne({ id: req.params.id },{})` is an asynchronous function, so you have no idea when it will be executed. As you are rendering the page from outside the function callback, it would seem that entry is not modified before the rendering call occurs.

As mentioned in the above answer, one way to do this is by creating a callback function, and rendering the page from inside the callback. That would be as @Mykola showed. For sake of clarity, I'm giving it below.

```
var collection = db.collection(req.params.collection);
   collection.findOne({ id: req.params.id },{}, function(error, data){
     if(error){
       console.log("Error: " + error);
     }
     else {
       res.render('dataentry',{ title: 'Information for: ' + req.params.collection + ' ' + req.params.id +'.', data: data});
     }
   });
```

This should work fine. That being said, there is another way to make the rendering operation wait till the asynchronous function finishes execution. That can be done using promises.

That can be done like:

```
var collection = db.collection(req.params.collection);
res.promise(collection.findOne({ id: req.params.id },{},function(error,data)).then(function(){
    res.render('dataentry',{ title: 'Information for: ' + req.params.collection + ' ' + req.params.id +'.', data: data});
});
```

I haven't checked my code, but hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on promises. May look into this further as well.

Comment: Always happy to help!

Comment: Looks like I am running into "Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters" error when finding by _id. If I change it to collection.findOne({ item: req.params.id } and the url param matches an item then it does not throw the error. Looking into the MongoDB documentation on _id I know there is something with the ObjectID but its way over my head to understand the issue. Are you familiar with this error that you could further explain it?

Comment: Hey. The way I understand it, an ObjectID is generated by the db containing a timestamp for an object. That way, every object has a unique ObjectID. By default, the _id key contains the ObjectID value. You can generate your own _id, but ObjectID is generated by the db. Your _id variable can have any number of characters as you want, but the size of an ObjectID variable is fixed. Try and open up your mongo cli interface and type `db.<collection name>.find().pretty() to see how your db is structured. Seems as if you're trying to retrieve from db by equating ObjectID with your generated _id.